# Seeking for smallest(minimum) and second smallest value of set of 2D functions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, maxima-minima

I have an algorithm in which I generate $$f^i(x,y)$$ in a loop running for **n** times. I want to calculate the smallest($f_{min1}$) and the second smallest ($f_{min2}$) values of all $f^i$s in all $(x, y)$ points. A brute-force way to do so is too keep all the $f^i$s and calculate the desired functions ($f_{min1}$) and ($f_{min2}$) having all the values for all $f^i$s. However, this method is unfortunately very time and memory consuming (saving all values and sorting all of the functions at all of the points and ...).

I am seeking for a way to do this iteratively. i.e. that I want to calculate the $f^j_{min1}$ and $f^j_{min2}$ by having the values of functions $f^j$, $f_{min1}^{j-1}$ and $f_{min2}^{j-1}$ . ($j$ is the iterator counter and $f^j_{min1}$ is the value of the minimum considering $f^i$ for $i = 0$ to $j$)

This approach for calculating $f_{min1}^{j}$ is feasible using:

$$
f_{min1}^j = \min(f_{min1}^{j-1}, f^j) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$

However, I could not find such a formulation for updating $f_{min2}^j$.
I would really appreciate it if someone can help find a way to calculate $f_{min2}$ similar to (*) without the need of keeping all the $f^i$s in the memory. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I have got the answer now. So in my iterative scheme, I might have one of these three situations for my $f^j(x,y)$

1. $f^j(x,y) >= f_{min2}(x, y)$

   -in this case neither $f_{min1}(x, y)$ nor $f_{min2}(x, y)$ updates.
2. $f_{min1}(x, y) < f^j(x,y) < f_{min2}(x, y)$

   -in this case $f_{min2}(x, y)$ gets replaced by $f^j$
3. $f^j(x,y) <= f_{min1}(x, y)$

   -in this case  $f_{min2}(x, y)$ gets replaced by $f_{min1}(x, y)$ and $f_{min1}(x, y)$ gets replaced by $f^j$

Comment: That's not enough. Think of what happens if the values are $f^0=3, f^1=2, f^2=1$. After processing the first two, you have $f_{\min1}=2,f_{\min2}=3$. Then after processing $f^j=1$, do you have the second smallest value in $f_{\min2}$?

Comment: In case 3, you need to update both, bumping the old winner to second place.

Comment: It is correct and I think this concludes the answer

Comment: Yes, looks good now.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need $j$ on $f_{\min 1}$ and $f_{\min 2}$.  The $=\min()$ update is just shorthand for an IF-THEN-ELSE expression in which you compare the current $f^j$ to the incumbent $f_{\min 1}$ and replace $f_{\min 1}$ if $f^j$ is better. To generalize to $f_{\min 2}$, use a nested IF in which the outer IF compares to $f_{\min 2}$, and the inner IF compares to $f_{\min 1}$ and replaces one or both.

Comment: The problem is the following: In updating $f_{min1}(x,y)$ one can simply choose the minimum of $f_{min1}(x,y)$ and $f^j(x,y)$ and replace the value of $f_{min1}(x,y)$. However, for $f_{min2}(x,y)$ it is not the case and the updated value is not equal to $\min(f_{min2}, f^j)$. Actually, the $\min(f_{min2}, f^j)$ is not what the $f_{min2}$ should be replaced by. And it cannot be handeled similar to $f_{min1}$ and very exactly I am asking what to calculate instead of $\min(f_{min2}, f^j)$ so I can use for updating f_{min2}.